# global variable or web sqlite which is preferable to use for browser

Tags: javascript, performance, browser-cache

is it good to use web Sqlite for storing bulk on data on browser or use global variables and also which browser supports sqlite?

Comment: From below 2 link i came to conclusion that we have to use **IndexDB** goto below link for more details. http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/01/14/html5-learn-how-to-use-indexeddb/ and https://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/standards/2011/the-limitations-of-websql-and-offline-apps/